How to show a more meaningful error in .NET API when enum value in body is invalid
I have an API endpoint in which the body has an enum.  If the value of the enum is invalid, the user will receive an error which is a bit hard to understand (in my opinion) something like:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-c3a28ee05a95aadf993ebcf7ecaea7d4-66d04142a844f335-00",
    "errors": {
        "command": [
            "The command field is required."
        ],
        "$.type": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[Domain.EnumType]. Path: $.type | LineNumber: 14 | BytePositionInLine: 18."
        ]
    }
}

To be consistent with similar errors, I'd prefer something like:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "Value": [
            "value [badvalue] is invalid."
        ]
    }
}

While I know I could get this behavior by changing the type from enum to string, I'd prefer not to do that as we are using swagger and with enums, swagger is able to show the possible enum values, which I think is valuable.
I am wondering if it is possible in .NET without too much effort to both have the benefits of using enums (clearly indicate the allowed values) and also have an easy to understand error message when the value is not a valid enum.
Thanks for any help and suggestions,
Eric

You can try to solve this with a custom validation attribute.

Check if the Enum value is valid in the IsValid method
Update the error message in FormatErrorMessage


I am not certain, but I believe I have already tried this.  But unfortunately, as I understand it, the serialization error occurs before the validation, so this approach did not work.
